# Why my localhost doesn't load a website? PHP - Fedora

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I'm working on Fedora 32 and I have a problem with php project. So, when I enter *`localhost/ProjectDir`* in my web browser, it lists all files that are in `ProjectDir`.

And that's fine... but when I try to test run my project (website of that project), so I enter `*localhost/ProjectDir/public*`, which has `index.php` inside - the error shown below occurs.

[image]

I have no idea what's wrong with that - I have set permission to `775`, changed group that this directory belongs to (from kinda `user-group` to `apache`). Does anybody have an idea how to solve that problem? What else can I do?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using apache as the webserver. You need to make sure that every file and folder (also it's parent folders) are accessible. (Usually group and owner set to `www-data` but it might be `apache` for fedora, I only used it on debian)

Comment: Yes, I do use apache - it's apache group for fedora... Should I add my user to group 'apache' or just my project files (with project directory itself)?

Comment: Having your user in the group makes it a bit easier to edit the files. Nevertheless you need to make sure than the full path (starting at the webroot; looks like it's `/var/www/html`) to your file is accessible by apache. In your case, if you only set the group (and not the user), make sure that the directory has `rwx` permissions for the group. (In order to create files)

Comment: Further reading for permissions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Viewing_permissions (More specifically the table for "Effect on files" & "Effect on directories" is helpful in this case)

Comment: its simple permission issue

Comment: ```Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/html/Kamaz/var/cache/dev/profiler).``` after I have changed permissions to ```775``` for whole ```Kamaz/var``` and changed group to ```apache```. 
Should I restart my PC after permission change? That's stupid question, but I have no idea what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

as written in the exception, you need to add write permission for the web-server. First possible solution would be to set the owner or the group of the folder to www-data. Another solution would be to allow "others" to write in this folder. I would not recommend the second solution, because it could be less secure.

Comment: ```Unable to create the storage directory (/var/www/html/Kamaz/var/cache/dev/profiler).``` after I have changed permissions to ```775```  for whole ```Kamaz/var``` and changed group to ```apache```.
Should I restart my PC after permission change? That's stupid question, but I have no idea what's wrong with that.

Comment: Did you try logging as root/sudo? Then you may also change the owner of the directory.